# Mortgage Refinance: What is Yield Spread Premium?

Tags: mortgage, refinance

I have a GFE from a broker that contains a hefty (>$8000) Origination Charge that includes a 2% Yield Spread Premium, and a credit for the whole of that amount. The rate is good and the broker insists there are no points to pay, but I suspect that what will happen is that once underwriting starts the YSP will suddenly drop and I'll effectively be paying points at closing anyway. The broker claims that any differences in the YSP when underwriting starts will be covered by them, but when I asked if they would put that in writing he said that they could not.

Is this normal practice? Should I be nervous?

Comment: Sounds like a good time to get other quotes, at the very least.

Comment: If I can get a rate lock before returning the disclosures, I should be covered, right? They can't change the Origination Charge or the credit after the lock.

Comment: I'd find out what parts of that are covered by the regulation requiring changes from the GFE to be eaten by the mortgage broker.  Many things are required to be close to the GFE and if not close can't be charged to you; I don't know about a yield spread premium (and I don't know what that is, so...) though.